# How do I get $\beta$ from $b$ in a simple regression?

Tags: regression

As I guess we all know, $\beta$ is the standardized version of $b$, which is the estimated slope parameter. However, how do I calculate it? I assume I have to divide $b$ by some kind of standard deviation. Any useful reference? I know there are other formulas, but I want to know how to get it from $b$.

Comment: I've removed the tag "beta distribution", which doesn't apply at all.

Comment: Just a note to say that "we all know" varies by discipline; for example, $\beta$ is sometimes used to refer to what you term $b$, whether standardized or not.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is much simpler.
To get $\beta$ instead of $b$, all you have to do is standardize your $x$ and your $y$ are run a regression of the standardized $y$ on the standardized $x$. Consider a simple bivariate model: $$y=x\beta+u$$

Here, $\beta$
  measures the marginal effect of x
  on the conditional mean of y
 . Now, let us standardize both $x$
  and $y$
  as :$$\tilde{y}=\frac{y-\mu_{y}}{\sigma_{y}}$$
 where $\mu_{y}$
 denotes the mean of y
  and $\sigma_{y}$
  denotes the standard deviation of $y$.
  Do a similar transformation for $x$.
  Then run the regression:$$\tilde{y}=\tilde{x}b+u$$
  and you will estimate the slope paramter in standard deviation units.

**If you want to use the OLS estimate directly, just multiply $\hat{\beta}$ with $\frac{\sigma_{x}}{\sigma_{y}}$.**